# Android Studio 4.2 doesn't show signing report in the Gradle bar

Tags: android, firebase, android-studio, code-signing-certificate

I'm starting a new project using Firebase and I have to get an SHA1 key from my project. Recently I've updated Android Studio to version 4.2 and the signing report tab disappeared from the Gradle bar.

**Follow the image :**

[image]

How can I get SHA1 easily in android studio 4.2?

Comment: I too have the same error. Did it work on 4.1 ? I'm thinking on downgrading to the previous versions. Some users have suggested if you use  gradlew signingReport in the terminal you should get the sha1 keys. Didn't work for me. Keep getting errors. Let me know if u succeed .

Comment: Did you find any solution for this. I'm having the same error. Please update your answer if you succeed.

Answer (score 87, accepted):

1. Click on right hand side gradle icon

[image]

2. Type `gradle signingReport` in the terminal

[image]

then you get the desired SHA fingerprint.

Comment: somehow my android studio does not have this signingReport when i search it... any idea why?

Comment: @WeiXiong which android studio version you are using?

Comment: @WeiXiong actually I am not aware of your situation, as I was also stuck with this issue and got above mention answer after searching a bit. This research helps me so I thought to upload this as well. I will try to find your situation's solution. If I get any solution I will update you as well.

Comment: @WeiXiong I will suggest you to build a release debug apk first then try to search `gradle signingreport `

Comment: @WeiXiong if the below-mentioned solution worked then it must get rated.

Comment: yep, did give it a "useful" vote, was 3 up previously :)

Comment: @Wei Xiong I didn't see either, but I just hit enter and it works!

Comment: for me gradlew singinReport worked as mentioned by @awaiking

Comment: Event if it's not showing, just type "gradle signingReport" and hit enter. It works!

Comment: @LạngHoàng Thanks Same in my case

Answer (score 28):

in terminal type

> gradle signingReport

and must pres

> Ctrl+enter

keys

[image]

[image]

Comment: for me gradlew singinReport worked as mentioned by @awaiking

Comment: None of the methods worked, search did not show signing report, refresh/re-sync Gradle did not work. Only this worked! Thanks a lot!!!

Answer (score 20):

Unchecked the '**Do not build gradle task list during gradle sync**' and click 'OK'.

[image]

Now press the gradle button again and you will see the options

[image]

Now press signing report to get SHA1

Answer (score 11):

> #### One of the ways to get the SHA1 key is by using Terminal:

- Open **`Terminal`** in android studio.
- Type **`./gradlew signingReport`** and press Enter.

[image]

Answer (score 8):

I struggled with this too. The latest update (Currently: Android Studio 4.2.1) didn't have the `Tasks` options under `Gradle` > `app`

Instead, go to the terminal and type `gradlew signingReport`

Answer (score 8):

**Step 1:** open setting click on the "Experimental" option 
**step 2:** uncheck---> "do not build Gradle task list during Gradle sync"
 **step 3:** sync your project again
now u can see the signing report in the Gradle tab

Answer (score 4):

First you are getting like this screen:
[image]

Now you have go to Settings > Experimental > And uncheck > Do not build gradle task list during gradle sync.
[image]

Then you have **sync project** must and then it will shows you sigin report
[image]

Comment: It worked for Windows 11. Android Studio 4: Bumblebee

Comment: yes it work on bumblebee

Answer (score 3):

Go to terminal and type command 'gradle signingReport' and press CTRL and then only ENTER

Answer (score 3):

Don't go to gradle present in right-side corner.

simply type **gradlew signingReport** in your terminal.

Answer (score 1):

In the Android Studio 4.2.1v the command on console is: gradlew singinReport

The command above wasn't recognized in the newer version

Answer (score 1):

You can also do that without Android Studio the manual way:

### Debug

```
keytool -list -v -keystore ~/.android/debug.keystore -alias androiddebugkey -storepass android -keypass android
```

### Release

```
keytool -list -v -keystore {PATH_TO_RELEASE_KEYSTORE} -alias {RELEASE_KEYSTORE_ALIAS}
```

Answer (score 0):

One new Android studio 4.2.1,

1. Click on Gradle on the right most side of screen
2. Click on Execute Gradle Task Button
3. Type like this: your_app_name [signingReport]

Type like this

[image]

Answer (score 0):

If the above gradle bar search wasn't working for you, You and I on the same page. The correct answer for those who are struggling with gradle search.
Goto to Android Terminal [left-bottom side], in terminal type this command "gradlew signingReport". Be sure you are putting "w" in the suffix. I hope this will be helpful for all future developers. Thankyou!!

Answer (score 0):

Very Simple!
... go to your **Buil.gradle**(Project:<app_name>)...
Remove the **Maven()** line...
It is deprecated and is preventing the signingReport from showing!
Then Sync/Rebuild.

Answer (score 0):

I resolve this issue by using this line of code
.\gradlew signingReport