# I cant find SHA-1 fingerprint Certificate on my gradle as it is not showing the :app folder

Tags: android, firebase, android-studio, gradle

[here is the snapShot of the right side panel](https://i.stack.imgur.com/gMCOA.png)

**how can i get that**

Comment: same issue in this topic
[android studio 4.2 doesnt show signing report in gradle bar](https://stackoverflow.com/a/67546584/11365488)

Comment: Does this answer your question? [android studio 4.2 doesnt show signing report in gradle bar](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/67490537/android-studio-4-2-doesnt-show-signing-report-in-gradle-bar)

Answer (score 1):

Its under the Tasks -> Android-> signingReport.

Comment: http://android-er.blogspot.com/2012/12/displaying-sha1-certificate-fingerprint.html check this more information.