# How to get SHA1 and SHA256 in Android Studio 4.2.1

Tags: android, android-studio

Generally we can SHA certificate fingerprints from
Gradle (in right hand side of Android Studio) > Task > Android > signingReport

But in Android Studio Latest Update 4.2.1 the Task is not showing option to get the SHA fingerprint

So can anyone help me with that?

Comment: Maybe this reponse can help you: https://stackoverflow.com/a/67493124/4871526

Comment: And you can see this for why not showing: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/67405791/gradle-tasks-are-not-showing-in-the-gradle-tool-window-in-android-studio-4-2

Answer (score 32, accepted):

**Option 1 :**
Just goto gradle option (in the right side) then click on the gradle icon in the left-top side of the popup

[image]

then a popup will appears with "Run Anything" name
, then type "**gradle signingReport**" and press enter

[image]

Then you will get the SHA in run tab

**Option 2 :**
In Android Studio 4.2.1 the Gradle task list is disabled by default
You can re-enable it from: Settings > Experimental > **Do not build Gradle task list during Gradle sync**.

Comment: If the signatureReport does not appear in the tooltips, just write it yourself and enter.

Answer (score 2):

I do not have this option in Gradle window. But what works perfectly fine to open terminal window and just type

macOS:

```
./gradlew signingReport
```

Windows:

```
.\gradlew signingReport
```

You need to have Java >= 11

Answer (score 0):

The Android Studio answer is now obsolete and the command line solution above is the only way to get the key hashes.