# How to get the SHA-1 fingerprint certificate in Android Studio 4.2.1

Tags: android, android-studio

After update Android Studio to version 4.2.1, I can not find the signing report in Grade anymore. Does anyone know where is it or is there another way to get SHA-1 and SHA-256?

[image]

Comment: Can you manually generate it like in this : https://developers.google.com/android/guides/client-auth

Answer (score 1, accepted):

At the bottom of editor, there's a terminal, click on it and write the following command:

`keytool -exportcert -alias your-key-name -keystore /path/to/your/keystore/file -list -v`

There is bunch of lines , look for `sha1`, that's your sha1 fingerprint

Above command is in single line.

Answer (score 1):

**Option 1 :**
Just goto gradle option (in the right side) then click on the gradle icon in the left-top side of the popup

[image]

then a popup will appears with "Run Anything" name
, then type "**gradle signingReport**" and press enter

[image]

Then you will get the SHA in run tab

**Option 2 :**
In Android Studio 4.2.1 the Gradle task list is disabled by default
You can re-enable it from: Settings > Experimental > **Do not build Gradle task list during Gradle sync**.

You can refer to this answer also :
https://stackoverflow.com/a/67607465/11736394